# Bundling all dependencies in .aar file

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, artifacts

I have an SDK project that is referencing quit alot of dependencies in gradle. I have to ask the SDK users to add those dependencies when they use the SDK in their projects. The problem is, *every time I add some new dependency or replace current dependency with a new one, I'll have to ask the users to make changes as well*, which is not a good practice in my opinion. Is there a way to bundle all the dependencies in the .aar. I am generating the artifact file with the following code.

```
uploadArchives{
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        def deployPath = file(getProperty('aar.deployPath'))
        repository(url: "file://${deployPath.absolutePath}")
        pom.project {
            groupId 'myPackageName'
            artifactId 'wingoku-io'
            version "0.0.6"
        }
    }
```

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have added the following method in uploadArchives method. The size of the artifact file has increased but when I use the .aar file in app project, it can't find the files.

```
uploadArchives{
        repositories.mavenDeployer {
            def deployPath = file(getProperty('aar.deployPath'))
            repository(url: "file://${deployPath.absolutePath}")
            pom.project {
                groupId 'myPackageName'
                artifactId 'wingoku-io'
                version "0.0.6"
            }

            **configurations.all {
                transitive = true
            }**
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following code because @aar was generating errors (couldn't find xx.xx.xx.aar on jcenter()). This still fails, the d

```
 compile ('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0'){
        transitive=true
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+@aar'){
        transitive=true
    }
    compile ('de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'){
        transitive=true
    }
```

Dalvik throws following warnings for all classes:

**dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lio/wingoku/sdk/Fetch$6;' failed**

It eventually throws exception **ClassDefNotFound**

Comment: can you post your dependencies section ?

Comment: look carefully the logs to see another warning complaining about multiple version of the same lib. (maybe support lib ?)

Comment: Nope I couldn't find any warning regarding multiple versions of the same lib. I used your dependency module as well. Still ClassDefNotFoundError is being thrown.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit

```
configurations.all {
    transitive = true
}
```

I'm not sure it as any effect.

I think you should write something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0'{
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+@aar'{
        transitive=true
    }
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'{
        transitive=true
    }
}
```

It just say that

- cardview is aar to include in this library.
- eventbus and socket.io-client are jar lib to include in aar

Comment: Can you please explain what will this do?

Comment: It is giving error: Gradle DSL method `compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0@aar'` not found